# how to use a derived type for sync.Map

Tags: go

My goal is to have a custom type the one I could derive and add extra methods, for example, when using a [map](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) this works:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myMap map[string]string

func (m *myMap) Add() {
    _, ok := (*m)["test"]
    println(ok)
}

func main() {
    x := &myMap{}
    fmt.Printf("x = %+v\n", x)
}
```

But if want the same with [sync.Map](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/syncmap) how to do it? I am currently trying this: https://play.golang.org/p/8PjpPY-Sjq

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type myMap sync.Map

func (m *myMap) Add() {
    _, ok := (*m).Load("test")
    println(ok)
}

func main() {
    x := &myMap{}
    fmt.Printf("x = %+v\n", x)
}
```

But get this error:

```
(*m).Load undefined (type myMap has no field or method Load)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)
>
> A struct is a sequence of named elements, called fields, each of
>   which has a name and a type. Field names may be specified explicitly
>   (IdentifierList) or implicitly (EmbeddedField). Within a struct,
>   non-blank field names must be unique.
>
> ```
> StructType    = "struct" "{" { FieldDecl ";" } "}" .
> FieldDecl     = (IdentifierList Type | EmbeddedField) [ Tag ] .
> EmbeddedField = [ "*" ] TypeName .
> Tag           = string_lit .
> ```
>
> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an
>   embedded field. An embedded field must be specified as a type name T
>   or as a pointer to a non-interface type name *T, and T itself may not
>   be a pointer type. The unqualified type name acts as the field name.
>
> A field or method f of an embedded field in a struct x is called
>   promoted if x.f is a legal selector that denotes that field or method
>   f.
>
> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they
>   cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.
>
> Given a struct type S and a type named T, promoted methods are
>   included in the method set of the struct as follows:
>
> - If S contains an embedded field T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T. The method set of *S
>     also includes promoted methods with receiver *T.
> - If S contains an embedded field *T, the method sets of S and *S both include promoted methods with receiver T or *T.

---

Use an embedded field of a `struct`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type myMap struct {
    sync.Map
}

func (m *myMap) Add(key, value interface{}) bool {
    _, loaded := m.LoadOrStore(key, value)
    return !loaded
}

func main() {
    x := &myMap{}
    k := "test"
    ok := x.Add(k, 42)
    fmt.Println(ok)
    v, ok := x.Load(k)
    fmt.Println(k, v, ok)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/YCNeiYVhlT

Output:

```
true
test 42 true
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)
>
> For a primary expression x that is not a package name, the selector
>   expression
>
> ```
> x.f
> ```
>
> denotes the field or method f of the value x (or sometimes *x; see
>   below). The identifier f is called the (field or method) selector; it
>   must not be the blank identifier. The type of the selector expression
>   is the type of f. If x is a package name, see the section on qualified
>   identifiers.
>
> A selector f may denote a field or method f of a type T, or it may
>   refer to a field or method f of a nested embedded field of T. The
>   number of embedded fields traversed to reach f is called its depth in
>   T. The depth of a field or method f declared in T is zero. The depth
>   of a field or method f declared in an embedded field A in T is the
>   depth of f in A plus one.
>
> Rule 1:
>
> For a value x of type T or *T where T is not a pointer or interface
>   type, x.f denotes the field or method at the shallowest depth in T
>   where there is such an f. If there is not exactly one f with
>   shallowest depth, the selector expression is illegal.

---

Sometimes, there is ambiguity in complex cases of nested embedding. If so, specify the full qualifiers explicitly. For example, `m.Map.LoadOrStore` and `x.Map.Load`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type myMap struct {
    sync.Map
}

func (m *myMap) Add(key, value interface{}) bool {
    _, loaded := m.Map.LoadOrStore(key, value)
    return !loaded
}

func main() {
    x := &myMap{}
    k := "test"
    ok := x.Add(k, 42)
    fmt.Println(ok)
    v, ok := x.Map.Load(k)
    fmt.Println(k, v, ok)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The line: `type myMap sync.Map` defines a new type based on an existing type.

According to the [Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations):

> A defined type may have methods associated with it. It does not
>   inherit any methods bound to the given type

It means, that `myMap` only inherits the fields of `sync.Map` (which is a `struct`) but not it's methods. It doesn't work like class inheritance in other languages.

Specifically, `sync.Map` does not have any exported fields, so using it to define a new type is pointless. 
Instead you should define a `struct` type that contains `sync.Map` as a field. Then you'll have access to it's methods. @peterSO's answer shows how to do that.